# Are questions on numerical analysis on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Can we ask questions on numerical analysis here? Prompted by the question: [Approximation techniques for the square super-root function?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/57/approximation-techniques-for-the-square-super-root-function)

The comments on the question say:

> Great question, but seemingly not DSP-related - may be better suited to e.g. math.stackexchange.com ? – Paul R
>
> are you sure you meant to ask this in Signal processing? It's a good question, but I think it would be a better fit on math.SE. – yoda
>
> While this could be on-topic on math.SE too, I see the interest of this question to signal processing people, where processor speed often is a limiting factor. – Tim
>
> I see DSP literature dealing with these kinds of questions more often than pure mathematical literature. Any math references I could find would obviously be useful, but wouldn't necessarily have the implementation details of a more engineering-oriented approach. Questions like this one come up frequently when attempting to port DSP algorithms to embedded platforms, but the knowledge required for implementation isn't specific to any particular platform, and isn't strictly mathematical. That's my reasoning for the question, at least. – datageist
>
> This is a numerical-methods question. As such, it can be asked on Stackoverflow as well as Math.SE. (And also one of the computational science sites if they are launched in the future.) Asking it on DSP in the hope that "some DSP people might know a better way of doing this thing which ought to be solved by experts of another discipline", may result in zero answers for a long time. – rwong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the most important factor is how you want to apply it. Just like Super User and the Apple/Linux sites overlap, you fit into one community more than another, so its you ask your question with the community it fits best.

**If you want to use the numerical analysis to process DSP data, then I think it should be on-topic**

Comment: On the other hand, we wouldn't want typography questions about printing DSP output.

Comment: @Tim: But does that have anything to do with the task of processing a signal?

Answer (score 2):

There are some numerical analysis method which are specific to DSP/image processing & computer vision . For example fractional optimization which is ubiquitous in bundle adjustment and 3D reconstruction, robust statistics and some other. Compressed sensing while being almost pure numerical even sounding like DSP and used mostly in DSP/vision. In those areas relevant receipts could be often more easily found in DSP/image/vision papers than numeric papers. IMHO it's ok to ask numerical methods questions here, but preferably with reference to specific DSP application(which is useful by itself).